# Interpreting ANOVA results

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I have 2702 records with one target variable (Y) and 11 independent/predictor variables (X1-X11).
[image]
I am doing multivariable regression to understand if I can predict Y using X or if there is any correlation between Y and X's.

Here is the ANOVA result.
[image]
Conclusion 1: Since my R square is low,I do not have a good model. The independent variables I have are not doing a good job/ or are not enough to explain the variation in Y.

Confusion 1: Since the p value for individual variables are significant, can I conclude that there is a strong correlation between Y and X1,X2,X3,X7,X8,X10,X11??

Confusion 2: Even though the p value is significant, there is no difference in correlation between significant variables and non-significant variables.
[image]

So I am really confused how to interpret my result. I feel like saying " there is no relation between Y and X based on Conclusion 1 and Confusion 2 but again how do I interpret confusion 1.

Any help would be appreciated, and I also want to know what kind of material can I study to get to solve my lack of understanding in these kind of scenarios. I feel like i am missing a piece in my understanding of data science.

Based on the result, what can we say about the data?

Answer (score 2):

> Conclusion 1: Since my R square is low,I do not have a good model. The
>   independent variables I have are not doing a good job/ or are not
>   enough to explain the variation in Y.

Maybe. Some problems I encountered consider >0.95 $R^2$ "good", other problems I had was fine with just >0.30 $R^2$. 0.44 $R^2$ means your model can account for abour 44% of the variability. Wherther it's good or bad depend on the problem domain. Please seek a consultant.

> Confusion 1: Since the p value for individual variables are
>   significant, can I conclude that there is a strong correlation between
>   Y and X1,X2,X3,X7,X8,X10,X11??

**Definitely not**. Significant predictors are not indication of correlation or/and importance of the predictor. http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/how-to-identify-the-most-important-predictor-variables-in-regression-models has more information. Add to your confusion, insignificant predictors could also be important. You can't just look at the table like that.

Some of your variables might be highly correlated. Look at **X4 and X5**. They have the identical values in your screenshot. They are both in-significant, but that can be caused by multicollinearity. That doesn't mean **X4 or X5 or a linear combination of them** should be omitted in the model.

What you can say:

> There is strong linear relationship in the model as the F statistics
>   is highly significant. This is a good start. However, the model is
>   suspicious victim of multicollinearity and overfitting. Further
>   investigation such as removing highly correlated variables is
>   necessary.